# Find cell with grepl & which

Tags: r, regex, readxl

I'm trying to find a cell in a data.frame that starts with a given pattern (I need to search rows AND columns).  The data.frames are coming from excel workbooks being read by `readxl` package.  The location of the pattern varies by workbook.  So in workbook 1 it might be in cell B12 but in workbook 2 it will be in C12.  However, once I find the 'anchor' cell I can look 1 cell to the right and find the numeric value I care about.

Currently I'm using this:

```
my_data <- iris
my_data$Species <- as.character(my_data$Species)
my_data[99,5] <- 'my_string'
my_data[109,5] <- 'my_string_too'

target_val <- 'my_string'
which(my_data == target_val, arr.ind = T)
```

This is good for exact matches but I'd like to get the functionality of `grepl` to use things like 'starts with' or 'OR' but can't figure out how to combine the two.  Is there a way to do something like this:

```
which(my_data[grepl('my_string|my_string_too', my_data, ignore.case = T)], arr.ind = T)
```

Comment: Use `'^(?:my_string|my_string_too)'` to check if a string starts with `my_string` or `my_string_too`

Comment: I am not sure I understand, do you mean like this: `which(sapply(my_data, function(x) grepl("^my_string", x)), arr.ind = TRUE)`. If not, can you clarify?

Comment: @Andrew  - that's exactly what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sapply()` which will output a matrix (in this case) and then use `which()` as you were using it before. Of course, this method extends to use with `%in%`, `startsWith()` or `endsWith()`, or using `grepl()` with `fixed = TRUE` if you are doing literal string matching.

```
which(sapply(my_data, function(x) grepl("^my_string", x)), arr.ind = TRUE)

     row col
[1,]  99   5
[2,] 109   5
```